# WebBrowser print programmatically with PDFCreator

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing, .net-3.5, pdf-generation

I'm trying to print programmatically multiple html pages from WebBrowser in VB.Net. The program I made is a web scraper that takes info about shipment from the shipment company's website and print the html page as pdf for every shipment code.
I selected PDFCreator as printer and I managed to print every html page, but PDFCreator shows a dialog window for every html to print. Is there a way to **programmatically select** the ***file name*** and the ***output path*** and print without **asking anything** to the user?

This is the sub to change the default printer:

```
Private Sub SetPrinter(ByVal printerName As String)
    Shell(String.Format("rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n ""{0}""", printerName))
End Sub
```

This is where the code prints the html:

```
 Private Function FindShipment(ByVal TrackingUrl As String, ByVal indexShipmentCode As Integer, ByVal shipmentCode as DataTable) As Boolean
    Try
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TrackingUrl)
        WaitForPageLoad()
        Dim trackingTextBox As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("id_ldv")
        trackingTextBox.InnerText = shipmentCode.Rows(indexShipmentCode).Item(0)
        'shipment code is a DataTable filled with info took from excel file
        WebBrowser1.Document.All("button").InvokeMember("click")
        WaitForPageLoad()
        WebBrowser1.Print()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

FindShipment is called inside a cycle, and the `WebBrowser1.Print()` opens a dialog window every cycle.